# System.JSONException: No mapping for apex type: Deserializing a Map which has managed package object as key and SF object as value

Tags: apex, managed-package, json

How can I get the exact same Map back which I serialized, when I deserialize it?

Here's the sample code:

//MPClass is a managed package class

```
Map<MPClass.mpObject, Account> mpObjAccObjMap = new Map<MPClass.mpObject, Account>();
MPClass.mpObject mpObj = new MPClass.mpObject();
mpObj.setValue('MPAccountId', '123xyz');
mpObj.setValue('Status', 'New');

Account acc = [Select Id, Address__c From Account Limit 1];
mpObjAccObjMap.put(mpObj, acc);
String jsonSerialized = JSON.serialize(mpObjAccObjMap);
//Works great till above code

//Fails at this deserialization:
Map<MPClass.mpObject, Account> mpObjAccObjMapDeserialized = (Map<MPClass.mpObject, Account>) JSON.deserialize(jsonSerialized, Map<MPClass.mpObject, Account>.class);
```

Error:

> System.JSONException: No mapping for apex type: MPClass.mpObject

Comment: Hi Harsha, what's the definition of the object `MPClass.mpObject`? If you have an attribute of type Object you probably won't be able to deserialize it using the JSON class.

Comment: global class mpObject

    Constructors (1):
    mpObject(String mpObjType)

    Methods (6) :
    List getArrayValue(String fieldname)
    String getNamespace()
    ANY getValue(String fieldname)
    String getMpType()
    void setValue(String fieldname, ANY value)
    void setValue(String fieldname, List value)